# Rails and element specific javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-4, canvas, asset-pipeline

I am new to rails/javascript and am confused as to what is going on in the following situation and how to resolve it. First I am trying manipulate a `canvas` element in the html using javascript like so:

```
 <canvas height='400' id='testLine' width='600'></canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas, ctx, w, h,
              world, boxBody, planeBody;

          init();
          animate();

          function init(){

            // Init canvas
            canvas = document.getElementById("testLine");
            ...do a bunch of stuff on the canvas
```

And the .haml source file:

```
%canvas{:id => 'testLine', :height => '400', :width => '600'}
:javascript
  var canvas, ctx, w, h,
            world, boxBody, planeBody;

        init();
        animate();

        function init(){

          // Init canvas
          canvas = document.getElementById("testLine");
```

I know that inlining javascript in rails is a bad move, but I'm not sure what to do here since if I load the javascript in question BEFORE the `canvas` element I get an error saying that the canvas element is not found. What should I do here, is the way I'm doing it the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to check that the page is loaded before running your scripts (no matter where they are included on the page) is to wrap your javascript jQuery `.ready()` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var canvas, ctx, w, h,
            world, boxBody, planeBody;

  init();
  animate();

  function init(){
    // Init canvas
    canvas = document.getElementById("testLine");
  }
});
```

Now you can load your scripts anywhere on the page and it won't be called until the page is loaded